# Increasing vertical distance above and below the fraction line

Tags: fractions

How can I increase the vertical distance above and below the fraction line (see the screenshot below)? Note, that I used `\displaystyle` for this term.

[image]

See my code here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

  \begin{align}
     = \frac{\displaystyle \int \biggl[ k_6 \cdot \exp{\int p(t) \,dt} \cdot  q(t) \,d t \biggr] + k_2 }{\displaystyle k_6 \cdot \exp{\int p(t) \,dt}} 
  \end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add suitable zero width rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\wfrac}[3][3pt]{%
  \frac{\wfracterm{depth}{\dp}{#1}{#2}}{\wfracterm{height}{\ht}{#1}{#3}}%
}
\newcommand{\wfracterm}[4]{%
  \sbox0{$\displaystyle#4$}%
  \vrule width 0pt #1 \dimexpr #20+#3\relax
  \usebox{0}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\wfrac{\int \biggl[ k_6 \cdot \exp{\int p(t) \,dt} \cdot  q(t) \,d t \biggr] + k_2 }
      {k_6 \cdot \exp{\int p(t) \,dt}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\wfrac[6pt]{\int \biggl[ k_6 \cdot \exp{\int p(t) \,dt} \cdot  q(t) \,d t \biggr] + k_2 }
      {k_6 \cdot \exp{\int p(t) \,dt}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to measure the numerator and add a zero width rule with some additional depth (default 3pt, adjustable with the optional argument); similarly, in the denominator we add the specified amount to the height.

The `\wfracterm` command is for convenience, in order to optimize the code. In the numerator we'll get

```
\vrule width 0pt depth \dimexpr\dp0+3pt\relax
```

and in the denominator

```
\vrule width 0pt height \dimexpr\ht0+3pt\relax
```

(where 3pt will be replaced by the optional argument, if given).

Comment: Thanks a lot @egreg :)

Comment: To @egreg: only for your information, I deleted the \cfrac in my description above. Also I replaced the \cfrac with the simple \frac in my code. Hope there is no confusion anymore.